# Return array from jest mock with React Hook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm trying to create a mock for a custom hook that makes use of useEffect and use/createContext and ultimately just returns something that looks like this:

```
[{ users: 0, hoursTested: 0, testDrives: 0 }, null];
```

My code is as follow:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import BetaResults from "./BetaResults";

var mockResults = [{ users: 0, hoursTested: 0, testDrives: 0 }, null];
jest.mock("services/EAPStats/useEAPStats", () => {
  console.log("In Mock");
  return jest.fn(() => {
    console.log("In jest.fn");
    console.log("mock results", mockResults);
    return mockResults;
  });
});
test("renders BetaResults", async () => {
  mockResults = [{ users: 10, hoursTested: 10, testDrives: 10 }, undefined];
  render(<BetaResults />);
  expect(screen.getAllByTestId("BetaResultsHeaderText").length).toEqual(1);
});
```

When I execute the test I receive this error:

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))]
```

Execution never reaches the function defined with jest.fn. What have I overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up going a different route with this and thought I'd post what I did for anyone else that struggles with implementing tests around React hooks and fetch calls. Rather than doing all of the mocking stuff, I just went with msw and it's much cleaner. Below is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import BetaResults from "./BetaResults";
import { rest } from "msw";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";

const server = setupServer(
  rest.get("/api/EAPStats.json", (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json({ users: 10, hoursTested: 1000, testDrives: 100 }));
  })
);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());
test("renders BetaResults", async () => {
  render(<BetaResults />);
  // Wait for the hook to fire and retrieve data. Initial render is loading component.
  await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId("resultsBackground"));
  expect(screen.getByTestId("hoursTested").innerHTML).toEqual("1000");
  expect(screen.getByTestId("users").innerHTML).toEqual("10");
  expect(screen.getByTestId("testDrives").innerHTML).toEqual("100");
});
```

Pretty straightforward and easy to see how to expand on this.